# Spacing multiple buttons using Gridbag on Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout, spacing

Im trying to space out all the buttons on the left side and the right side to a certain number of pixels from each bottom above and below it. When I put the message and message 2 JLabels to size of 1 pixel, then the spacing seems to work more closely to what I had anticipated.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so much friend! I greatly appreciate the help and explanation!! Thanks for the time, helped me greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout management really is about separation of concerns.  No one layout manager will do EVERYTHING you want ALL the time.  You need to be willing to split your UI into sections and manage those sections individually, for example, you have a left menu, a right menu and a center message area, each of these has it's own layout requirements, as does the main view (left menu, messages, right menu)

You could use a `GridLayout` as the core layout and layout each of the other sections within it, for example...

[image: Menu01]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LayoutManagement extends JComponent {

    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11;

    final JLabel message = new JLabel("Default Message");
    final JLabel message2 = new JLabel("Default Message");

    public LayoutManagement() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        JPanel centerPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        add(buildLeftPane());
        add(centerPane);
        add(buildRightPane());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        gbc.weightx = 0;

        message.setBackground(Color.pink);
        message.setOpaque(true);
        message.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 50));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        centerPane.add(message, gbc);

        message2.setBackground(Color.pink);
        message2.setOpaque(true);
        message2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 50));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        centerPane.add(message2, gbc);

    }

    public JPanel buildLeftPane() {

        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        b1 = new JButton("This");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b1.setOpaque(true);
        b1.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 0);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("This");
            }

        });

        pane.add(b1, gbc);

        b2 = new JButton("class");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b2.setOpaque(true);
        b2.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("class");
            }
        });

        pane.add(b2, gbc);

        b3 = new JButton("will");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b3.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b3.setOpaque(true);
        b3.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("will");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b3, gbc);

        b4 = new JButton("give");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b4.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b4.setOpaque(true);
        b4.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("give");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b4, gbc);

        b5 = new JButton("you");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b5.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b5.setOpaque(true);
        b5.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("you");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b5, gbc);

        b6 = new JButton("practice");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b6.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b6.setOpaque(true);
        b6.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("practice");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b6, gbc);

        return pane;

    }

    public JPanel buildRightPane() {

        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        b7 = new JButton("creating");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        b7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b7.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b7.setOpaque(true);
        b7.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("creating");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b7, gbc);

        b8 = new JButton("and");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        b8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b8.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b8.setOpaque(true);
        b8.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("and");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b8, gbc);

        b9 = new JButton("laying");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        b9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b9.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b9.setOpaque(true);
        b9.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("laying");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b9, gbc);

        b10 = new JButton("out");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        b10.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b10.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b10.setOpaque(true);
        b10.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("out");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b10, gbc);

        b11 = new JButton("containers");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        b11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b11.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b11.setOpaque(true);
        b11.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("containers");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b11, gbc);

        return pane;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout Management Lab");
        frame.add(new LayoutManagement());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But, wait, the menu items are now out of alignment....hmmm...

We could still use the some concept, separation of concerns AND the power of `GridBagLayout`, so instead of laying out all the menu items and the message items in the same container, we could layout the menu items in the same container and the message items in there own container, but combine the two, for example...

[image: Better layout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;



public class LayoutManagement02 extends JComponent {

    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11;

    final JLabel message = new JLabel("Default Message");
    final JLabel message2 = new JLabel("Default Message");

    public LayoutManagement02() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel centerPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel menuPane = buildMenuPane();

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        gbc.weightx = 0;

        message.setBackground(Color.pink);
        message.setOpaque(true);
        message.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 50));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        centerPane.add(message, gbc);

        message2.setBackground(Color.pink);
        message2.setOpaque(true);
        message2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 50));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        centerPane.add(message2, gbc);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        menuPane.add(centerPane, gbc);

        add(menuPane);

    }

    public JPanel buildMenuPane() {

        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        b1 = new JButton("This");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b1.setOpaque(true);
        b1.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 0);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("This");
            }

        });

        pane.add(b1, gbc);

        b2 = new JButton("class");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b2.setOpaque(true);
        b2.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("class");
            }
        });

        pane.add(b2, gbc);

        b3 = new JButton("will");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b3.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b3.setOpaque(true);
        b3.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("will");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b3, gbc);

        b4 = new JButton("give");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b4.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b4.setOpaque(true);
        b4.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("give");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b4, gbc);

        b5 = new JButton("you");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b5.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b5.setOpaque(true);
        b5.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("you");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b5, gbc);

        b6 = new JButton("practice");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b6.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b6.setOpaque(true);
        b6.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("practice");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b6, gbc);

        b7 = new JButton("creating");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        b7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b7.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b7.setOpaque(true);
        b7.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("creating");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b7, gbc);

        b8 = new JButton("and");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        b8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b8.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b8.setOpaque(true);
        b8.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("and");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b8, gbc);

        b9 = new JButton("laying");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        b9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b9.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b9.setOpaque(true);
        b9.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("laying");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b9, gbc);

        b10 = new JButton("out");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        b10.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b10.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b10.setOpaque(true);
        b10.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("out");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b10, gbc);

        b11 = new JButton("containers");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        b11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b11.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b11.setOpaque(true);
        b11.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 5);
        b11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("containers");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b11, gbc);

        return pane;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout Management Lab");
        frame.add(new LayoutManagement02());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

That's a little better, but what about the spacing between the menu items??

Well, you can control the spacing between elements through the use of the `GridBagConstraints#insets` property, now `GridBagLayout` will make a copy of the constraints for each component when you add them to the container, this is great, this means you can use a single instance of the constraints to get the layout setup without effecting the other components.

This allows you to create a template of the constraints that most of the components will want to use and only change those values you need to for each individual component....

So, we could start with something like `gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 20, 2);` and have it applied to all the components without having to redefine it for each component!

Now, because we've separated the message components and the menu components, we can modify the way that the menu items are laid out, without adversely affecting the message components and the same works the other way, you can change the way that the message components are laid out without affecting the way the menu items are laid out...

[image: Spaced]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;



public class LayoutManagement02 extends JComponent {

    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11;

    final JLabel message = new JLabel("Default Message");
    final JLabel message2 = new JLabel("Default Message");

    public LayoutManagement02() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel centerPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel menuPane = buildMenuPane();

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.weightx = 0;

        message.setBackground(Color.pink);
        message.setOpaque(true);
        message.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 50));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        centerPane.add(message, gbc);

        message2.setBackground(Color.pink);
        message2.setOpaque(true);
        message2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 50));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        centerPane.add(message2, gbc);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        menuPane.add(centerPane, gbc);

        add(menuPane);

    }

    public JPanel buildMenuPane() {

        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        b1 = new JButton("This");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 20, 2);

        b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b1.setOpaque(true);
        b1.setBorderPainted(false);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("This");
            }

        });

        pane.add(b1, gbc);

        b2 = new JButton("class");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b2.setOpaque(true);
        b2.setBorderPainted(false);
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("class");
            }
        });

        pane.add(b2, gbc);

        b3 = new JButton("will");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b3.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b3.setOpaque(true);
        b3.setBorderPainted(false);
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("will");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b3, gbc);

        b4 = new JButton("give");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b4.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b4.setOpaque(true);
        b4.setBorderPainted(false);
        b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("give");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b4, gbc);

        b5 = new JButton("you");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b5.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b5.setOpaque(true);
        b5.setBorderPainted(false);
        b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("you");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b5, gbc);

        b6 = new JButton("practice");
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        b6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b6.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b6.setOpaque(true);
        b6.setBorderPainted(false);
        b6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message.setText("practice");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b6, gbc);

        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 20, 2);

        b7 = new JButton("creating");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        b7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b7.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b7.setOpaque(true);
        b7.setBorderPainted(false);
        b7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("creating");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b7, gbc);

        b8 = new JButton("and");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        b8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b8.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b8.setOpaque(true);
        b8.setBorderPainted(false);
        b8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("and");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b8, gbc);

        b9 = new JButton("laying");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        b9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b9.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b9.setOpaque(true);
        b9.setBorderPainted(false);
        b9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("laying");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b9, gbc);

        b10 = new JButton("out");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        b10.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b10.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b10.setOpaque(true);
        b10.setBorderPainted(false);
        b10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("out");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b10, gbc);

        b11 = new JButton("containers");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        b11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        b11.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        b11.setOpaque(true);
        b11.setBorderPainted(false);
        b11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                message2.setText("containers");
            }
        });
        pane.add(b11, gbc);

        return pane;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout Management Lab");
        frame.add(new LayoutManagement02());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```